# Forms command in MS Access Not Visible

Tags: forms, ms-access

I do not see in the ribbon of MSAccess the form group in the Create tab. How is possible? I tried using access 2013 and also 2016, and the issue remains.
Can someone help me?

i dont see this section:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/erBRo.png

Comment: Is it possible that the application in question has a custom ribbon? Try starting the application and hold down the shift key so that no code or forms load.  so, this could mean that a form or the application has a custom ribbon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `"Forms"` panel may need to be added manually in your ribbon, depending on the version you are using, you may try following steps, there might be slight variations in the labels.

1- Right Click in an empty space of your ribbon and select `"Customize the Ribbon"`

2- In the Access Options Window, under `"Customize the Ribbon"` section you will see two columns `"Choose commands from"` & `"Customize the Ribbon"`

3- Select `"Main Tabs"` under both columns, expand `"Create"` Tab, and then select `"Forms"` and click `"Add"` and click `"OK"` to finish adding the desired missing panels.